# How do I publish a Conan package locally?

Tags: cmake, conan

I'm new to Conan but experienced with cmake/make/studio etc.

I'm trying to build a simple program that uses a library (uWebSockets) that uses another library (uSockets) that uses another library (libuv). The libraries aren't important to the question, it's just that there's a chain of dependencies.

I found libuv in conan central and all ok.

The uSockets lib is makefile only but I added cmake and I think added Conan support. A sample compiles and runs, so I'll take that as ok.

But... How can I **use** my fresh uSockets lib locally?

I don't want to publish it anywhere, just use it in the build of uWebSockets, and then use **that** build for my executable.

I'm looking for something like "Conan publish local" I think.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The Github issues https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues is also a good way to get responses, it is possible to post general questions there too, not only for bug reports or feature requests.

Answer (score 11):

The [package creation process](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/creating_packages/getting_started.html) from sources is local. When you execute a `conan create`, it takes the recipe and sources from your local folder, put them in the Conan cache, builds the package as requested (every `conan create` will build a different configuration, you can use input settings `-s compiler.version=xxx` or use a full profile-recommended, to specify configurations).

When packages are in the local cache, they can be reused from any other project. Doing `conan install` will first look in the Conan cache, and only if the package is not found there, will try to look in configured `remotes`. If everything is found locally, it might not need internet connection at all.

Also, depends on what is your concern, you don't need to publish your packages to a public server, like [ConanCenter](https://conan.io/center/). You can use [Artifactory CE](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/uploading_packages/artifactory_ce.html) (free) to put your packages there, you could run it in your LAN, without external internet connection, and you could still reuse your binaries from there, without needing to rebuild from sources.

Comment: Thanks! This is the most compact summary I have seen so far. Really helped me to understand basic concepts of conan better.